# What happens if I add the starter edition to my Battle.net account once I already have a frozen WoW account?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, battle.net

I played WoW a year or so ago, and I still have it as "frozen" on my Battle.net account. I'd like to get back to playing, but I'd like to try the free version of it before actually buying game time, it might not be as good as before... So, I've added the starter version to my account, and I'm downloading it now, but will I be able to see my old characters? I know I probably wont be able to play them, because they're mostly level 80 or 85, but I'd like to have my new character (created on the starter addition) on that account as well, after I buy the actual game time.

Will he be on the same list as my older characters (given that I create him on the same realm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No your old account will be the same. This is going to be a completely new account, where you have limits (of the starter account).

I have tried this a while ago, for the same purpose. Didn't work as I wished =/

Comment: Damn it, that's too bad...